# data.table j operation using a temp variable and a by column

Tags: r, data.table

Can get the desired behaviour in two lines but the one liner fails (see code below). Suspect something to do with either the temp variable in j, or that using the column in both by and j as in fail-1, although fail-2 also gives NAs.

MWE and outputs (first is the desired) shown below:

```
library(data.table)
foostr <- "ab"
foodt <- data.table(v1 = letters[1:3], v2 = 1:3)

# desired output
bardt <- foodt[, .(v3 = sapply(.SD, grepl, x = foostr)), by = c("v1", "v2"), .SDcols = "v1"]
bardt[, v4 := .SD$v2*.SD$v3, by = "v1"]
print(bardt)
# v1 v2    v3 v4
# 1:  a  1  TRUE  1
# 2:  b  2  TRUE  2
# 3:  c  3 FALSE  0

# fail-1: NAs?
bardt <- foodt[, .(v3 = {foov3 = sapply(.SD, grepl, x = foostr)}, v4 = .SD$v2*foov3), by = c("v1", "v2"), .SDcols = "v1"]
print(bardt)
# v1 v2    v3 v4
# 1:  a  1  TRUE NA
# 2:  b  2  TRUE NA
# 3:  c  3 FALSE NA

# fail-2: NAs?
bardt <- foodt[, .(v3 = {foov3 = sapply(.SD, grepl, x = foostr)}, v4 = .SD$v2*foov3), by = c("v1"), .SDcols = "v1"]
print(bardt)
# v1    v3 v4
# 1:  a  TRUE NA
# 2:  b  TRUE NA
# 3:  c FALSE NA
```

Comment: Why are you copying the whole data set instead of just adding a new column to the exisitng one?

Comment: can't you just do `foodt[,':=' (v3=grepl("a|b", v1), v4=grepl("a|b", v1)*v2)]` ?

Comment: Or just `library(stringi) ; foodt[, v3 := v2 * stri_detect_fixed(foostr, v1)]` Or if you want both cols `foodt[, c("v3", "v4") := {v3 <- stri_detect_fixed(foostr, v1) ; v4 <- v3 * v2 ; .(v3, v4)}]`

Comment: ditto no argument on copying vs adding a column in terms of efficiency, just it is a small table the second and want it dropped after a function exits..., will checkout your suggestions. thanks.